# What is real and true type used in Frame of Window in macOS?

Tags: swift, cocoa

Let say my NSScreen.main size is **2560 X 1415** if I create a NSWindow and set the Size to **500 X 500** it would crated a window in screen and show it, I am trying to know what is the min value that make NSWindow change its size in Screen, I tried to change the width from 500 to 500.1 but it did not worked, if we look to CGRect it has Origen and Size, which we can use Double or CGFloat Type for them but in reality NSWindow works just with Int type and all of them internally going convert to Int! So in that case 1 Int means 1 Pixel here, and we cannot work on less than 1 pixel or less than 1.0 in updating size or origin in NSWindow, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real and true type is Double.

NSWindow frames are also rounded up to the next largest integer value (see [`NSIntegralRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1391136-nsintegralrect)). The resulting (real and true) type is still Double.

These are measured in points, not pixels. NSWindow is optimized to operate on point boundaries. NSViews can have fractional frames, but at the NSWindow level it is expanded to the next integral point. But it's still a Double.

Comment: So is right to say if give the value of 500.5 that would be 500.0 and also if I gave 500.6 that would be 501.0, if that is so in behaviour is more like a Int type even the real type is Double? I mean we would not be able to have a NSWindow with width of 500.1 or 500.9 but that would be just 500.0 or 501.0?

Comment: 500.5 should adjust to 501.0 (also 500.1 should adjust to 501.0). I created some quick test apps to verify and that's what I'm seeing. I don't ever expect the result to be smaller than requested. I don't know what you mean by "more like an Int than a Double." It is limited to integral values, but it's still absolutely a Double. Thinking of it as "Int" is just going to cause confusion (Int is not the same thing as a mathematical integer any more than Double is the same thing as mathematical reals).

Comment: It might be helpful to expand your question to explain what you're really after. If your question is just "can NSWindow have a size that is not representable by Int," the answer is no (that also applies to values larger than Int.max even thought they're valid Doubles). If it's "what is the type of the width of NSWindow's frame," the answer is Double.